# How to migrate from parse.com to buddy?

Tags: android, parse-platform, migrate, buddy.com

I need to migrate from parse.com to parseOnBuddy (https://buddy.com/parse/).
My application connected to new server. I can delete/insert/update data on new server. But push messages are not coming to my device. I've done server setting (FCM api key and sender_id [F.A.Q](https://buddy.com/parse/frequently-asked-questions/#push)). But nothing happens. What can I do ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is link with instructions:
[push instructions](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Parse-Server/wiki/Push-Configuring-Clients)

In my option - I have missed

```
<meta-data android:name="com.parse.push.gcm_sender_id"
  android:value="id:YOUR_SENDER_ID" />;
```